# Sway Presentation & HTML

Tags: office-365

Morning all,

I'm wondering if, for those that have played with Sway in Office365.  I'm trying to create a presentation in Sway that'll allow its viewers to navigate from one slide to another depending on where they click.  So, rather than a lineal deck, they'll have something that responds to what they click on.

So, I was wondering if Sway allows an editor to use either HTML or some fashion of setting an anchor that can then be clicked on.

Any ideas appreciated

Thanks
Steven